# I want to show unique list for every user who has signed in. How can I do this?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, reminders

I am creating a time reminder in which the user first logins and then set time reminder but for every account that is being created, the same reminder list is being shown in  reminder list view. How can I create unique list for every account?
Here is the Database Code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

// User table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// User Table Columns names
private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";


// Table name
private static final String TABLE_REMINDERS = "ReminderTable";

// Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT = "repeat";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_NO = "repeat_no";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_TYPE = "repeat_type";
private static final String KEY_ACTIVE = "active";


// create table sql query
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

// drop table sql query
private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    String CREATE_REMINDERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REMINDERS +
            "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_REPEAT + " BOOLEAN,"
            + KEY_REPEAT_NO + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_REPEAT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ACTIVE + " BOOLEAN" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REMINDERS_TABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a field of `user_id` on the `ReminderTable`, and set the `user_id` for each reminder when you create it. Then you can retrieve reminders for each user by using a `SELECT WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got your question.

If you want to have unique reminder list then save the reminder with some unique id, not the reminder id which is creating after every reminder is saving in a database but an ID which uniquely associated with a particular account.

The problem with your database is that it is saving the reminder but doesn't have any unique link that can say that this reminder belongs to this account.

So, you have to just add another parameter in your ReminderTable which store the email of a user which setting remainder, so that whenever he want to see his saved remainder you just fetch the list with reminder which have email address same to that of user who click to see his remainder.

Sorry for my english. Hope you got my answer. Please comment for queries.